# Link an image on the front page to post, but when the post is open link to the image. (WordPress)

Tags: php, image, wordpress, hyperlink

I have a wordpress blog: http://technosting.com/

On my homepage each post has an image before it, this image is linked to the post. Also when the post is opened the same image is still linked to the post URL. I use a fancybox plugin that makes a gallery of any photo that is linked to its self. For example just look at any of the other images inside the post, excluding the first image of coarse. I would like it so that on the front page the image is linked to the blog post as it is now but when the blog post is opened, I would like the image to link to its self so that the fancybox can be used to view the image. I looked for hours online but am not able to find any solution for this. How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: do you have the code that fancy box uses to display the images?

Comment: It just auto detects images. It is a WordPress Plugin.

Comment: We can't help you without code. You wanna look for the place in your code that outputs the images. Probably looks like:
output =. "html build up here";
output =. "html build up here";
output =. "html build up here";
And so on.

Answer (score 0):

What you want here, is [is_single()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single).

Add this in your functions.php

```
function enqueue_fancybox(){
    wp_enqueue_script('my_custom_js', '/path/to/my/custom.js', array('jquery', 'fancybox'));
}

if(is_single(){
    add_action('wp_head', 'enqueue_fancybox');    
}
```

Where `custom.js` calls the code required to create the fancybox. The code also indicates that it has a dependency on the enqueued scripts `jquery` and `fancybox`

This will ensure it's not fired on the front page, where it's pulling a list of multiple posts, because `is_single()` will return false, and the conditional expects true.

Comment: The fancybox plugin is already loaded throughout the whole site, it looks for links to image files then opens them in the fancybox. Maybe there is a way to do it using javascript or jQuery. When on the single.php link the image to its source. Using a certain maybe so that I can control only the images that need to work. Any idea on how to write something like that, I'm not very good at javascript.

Comment: @skoltyno Yes, there is. It's to do it just like I've indicated above. Where `custom.js` holds any calls to `$.fancybox()`. This way, you're only loading it on the page that you need.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from my problem has nothing to do with the fancybox. I need the image to link to its source when the single is open and when on the home page to link to the post.